# Is there any way to pop several pages and reload the destination page?

Tags: flutter

I'm setting up an app which have to fill a long 4-part form, which might be displayed in 4 sequential screens in a mobile application. Now on the 4th part of the form, there is a submit button. User clicks on Submit and all the previous screens should be popped and user should be taken back to the Item-List screen(1st screen) where the updated data items must be shown. We won’t be pushing anything new here, just going back to a previous route. But the first page should be reloaded. How is this possible?

Comment: did you try pop.until ?

Comment: pop.until is working but the designation page(i.e the !st page data is not reloaded. Any Idea?

Comment: yes when you are poping the previous pages are reloaded it just pop the last navigated page from navigator stack

Comment: I need to call a function when poped to destination page to reload from server

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**// Updated Answer**
So if this is your first screen where you are pushing and where you want to call a function when poped, this is how you can do it.

```
  Navigator.of(context)
    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterScreen()))
    .then((success) {
         if(success){
         // call your function here
         }

  });
```

Comment: if i go to second page and then pressed back button the first page will come and it will reload unnecessarly. I need to avoid that also. The 1st screen should only reload when the submit button in the 4th page is pressed. And that press should pop all the pages to reach the first page

Comment: For that you need to manage a state using bloc or provider. As a workaround you can pass a bool from 4 to 3 then 3 to 2 then 2 to 1. And if its true you can proceed.